# How to create android studio animation file

Tags: android, animation

In my android Project, I need to create an 'anim' folder. As most people know, the anim folder will be used to store animations. but how can we create this

i created like this way
Right click on "res" folder
then i choose Android resource Directory
then i created below animation file

### silde_up.xml:-

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
      android:fromydelta="100%"
      android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
      android:toxdelta="0">
    </translate>
</set>
```

when i run project i am getting errors like :-Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'fromydelta' in package 'android'

please help me how can we resolve this problem

Comment: mb replace "fromydelta" by "fromYDelta" ??

Answer (score 0):

Try android:fromYDelta and android:toXDelta